# How to create a DIV with static width

Tags: html, css

I have website [Click](http://calkieminnabajka.pl/)

When I resize a web browser (ex. firefox) image in right side go under. How can I fix it ? I want to display image, logo all the time. Only left site can change size like now.

Comment: Have you tried setting your css for your div using % instead of pixels...such as #myDiv {width:20%;}   ?  I wasn't sure if you meant the logo size can change too.

Comment: Try setting a `min-width` for `html,body` in your css

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just looking at it quickly you should set a % width to the right side div as well -your left side is 80% and your right is fixed at 200px. So when the 200 is over 20% cannot sit inline. Fixing that brings everything into view. You will also want to set the image max-width to 100% to keep it from overflowing. 
example css

```
#rightSite{
width:20%;
}
#rightSite img{
max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with some conflicting goals:

- You are trying to have a fixed-width right column.
- You want the main content area to automatically re-size to fit the screen.

Unfortunately, normal DIVs and CSS widths aren't great at handling this combination of fixed-width and dynamic-width.

One way to achieve your goal is to use a TABLE instead of the DIVS for the layout.  The nice thing about using TABLEs is that they work *everywhere*.  However, they do obscure the logical structure of your HTML, so many people don't like to use TABLEs for visual layout purposes.  If you don't want to use a TABLE, you can override the behavior of your DIVs so that they behave like TABLE CELLs.  By using this approach, you can get "the best of both worlds" -- nice visual CSS layout, and clean logical HTML layout.

Here is a demo of your website, which I believe has the behavior you are looking for:

http://demo.likebike.org/calkieminnabajka.pl/

Here are the adjustments I made:

1. I used the CSS "background" property on the "#site" DIV, instead of placing a background IMG in the HTML.  This was necessary to avoid ugly overlapping.
2. I removed all of the CSS properties from the '#background_overlay' and '#leftSite' DIVs.
3. I set the following CSS values:

   ```
   #site {
       display: table-cell;
       background: url(background.jpg);
   }
   #rightSite {
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: top;
       width: 200px;
       background-color: white;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

set `width` of `body` to `screen width`
you can also set the `min-width` property of body

```
<script>
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.style.width=screen.width+"px";
body.style.minWidth="1100px";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your display style

```
<div style='display: table-cell; width:50%'>
  Left div
</div>
<div style='display: table-cell; width:50%'>
  right div
</div>
```